# Привязать сертификаты к кластерам Service Fabric(перевод сервиса на https)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, azure

Задача состоит в том чтобы перевести сервис на работу по https, сервис публикуется через приложение типа Service Fabric. В публикуемом проекте в файле ServiceManifest.xml прописано

```
<Endpoints>
  <Endpoint Protocol="https" Name="SingleSignOnEndpoint" Type="Input" Port="8003" />
</Endpoints>
```

В файле ApplicationManifest.xml проекта Service Fabric

```
<Policies>
  <ContainerHostPolicies CodePackageRef="Code" Isolation="[SingleSignOn_Isolation]">
    <PortBinding ContainerPort="443" EndpointRef="SingleSignOnEndpoint" />
    <CertificateRef X509FindValue="[HttpsCertThumbprint]" Name="HttpsCert" />
  </ContainerHostPolicies>
</Policies>
```

Получаю сообщение: Не удалось выполнить сценарий PowerShell, Could not resolve parameter 'HttpsCertThumbprint'.

На сколько я понимаю у меня не определяется сертификат HttpsCertThumbprint, который используется Service Fabric по умолчанию. Подскажите кто сталкивался с такой задачей? Как создать сертификат и привязать его к кластеру, или возможно я не в том направлении копаю?

Comment: Вот хорошее руководство- https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-dotnet-app-enable-https-endpoint Правда у меня пока не запустилось